# Creating separate feeds for custom post types

Tags: custom-post-types, posts, templates, rss, feed

My site has a few custom post types, news, events, you-tube, etc. I'd like to create an rss feed for each post type as well as a main with all.

I've experimented an bit and found how to combine them into one but I haven't determined how to segment each. Do I need to create separate feed-rss.php for the templates as well as a custom function?

This is the function I'm currently using to combine them into one feed.

```
//Custom post feeds
function myfeed_request($qv) {
    if (isset($qv['feed']) && !isset($qv['post_type']))
        $qv['post_type'] = array('post', 'youtube', 'event', 'news' );
    return $qv;
}
add_filter('request', 'myfeed_request');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at this: http://www.seodenver.com/custom-rss-feed-in-wordpress/